# JAVA Creating a program using an array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have an array of 20 elements:

```
int[]a = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40};
```

The array starts from 1 and ends at 20. So everything is doubled. 1 = 2, 2 = 4, 4 =6, etc.

And I am trying to create a program that when the user selects a number say for example 30. It adds the total from place point 15 to 20. So 30 + 32 + 34 + 36 + 38 + 40).

How would I tell the program to calculate the total based on the number the user inputs?
I cannot seem to figure this out. Would I use a for statement? I'm lost. Any help would be great. I am new to Java.

Comment: good explanation of the question, but still you need to try and post some code, atleast search and get started, if stuck we all  will help you.

Comment: Show us what you tried until now, so we can help you...

Comment: I'm failing to see why you need the array if the relation to the index is how you say.

Comment: Actually, it starts at 0 and ends at 19...:)

Comment: Well see this would be my next question then. Can I perform calculations on an array to get those elements? If so does anybody have a good link or example on how to do that? Note: I want the array to start at 1 so I  can show that it is doubled.

Comment: Basically I want the user to enter a number and the computer to generate the rest up until 20.

Comment: Actually it's not very clear to me: if the user posts "30" why does the program need to sum from the 15th place to the 20th ?

Comment: Hint: The elements are formed by a linear progression. So you can deduce a specific element's index by applying a formula. Once you've got this index, you just need to iterate from that index onwards.

Answer (score 0):

*You can try something likewise,*

```
    int[]array = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40}; 

    System.out.println("Enter Your choice Number : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    int index = n/2;
    int sum = 0;
    if(index < array.length){
         for(int i = index;i<array.length;i++){
            if( i > index){
                System.out.print("+ ") ;
            }
            System.out.print(array[i]);
            sum += array[i];
          }
         System.out.println("Answer : " + sum);
       }
    else{
      System.out.println("InValid Value Entered, Try Again...!!");
    }
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[]a = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40}; 
    System.out.println("Enter the value"); 
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
      int in=s.nextInt();

      int sum=0;

      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      {
          if(in==a[i]){
              for(int j=i;j<a.length;j++){


                  sum=a[j]+sum;
                  System.out.println(sum+"===="+j); 
              }

              }
      }

    }
```